# Nginx times out when sending email with php (in wordpress), but the mail still sends

Tags: php, email, nginx

I have experimented with a number of wordpress plugins and just a raw php `mail()` script on my server which runs Nginx, php5 fastcgi.

Basically when a script tries to send an email using php's `mail()` function the page will hang in a loading state until eventually a Nginx 504 Gateway Time-out error page comes up.

Weirdly, the email is still sent fine but the fact the page hangs has prompted users to repeatedly hit the "send" button so often we'll get several of the same email.

I currently don't have access to my nginx/php error logs as I'm at work where SSH/ftp does not work but I'll post any relevant info when I can.

In the meantime is there a simple explanation for the above?

**UPDATE:**

Here are some example log entries from mail.log. Seems to do with the domain name being unqualified. How do I fix this? (Apologies this may be one for serverfault)

I have a lot of these (email address redacted):

```
Jul 27 17:26:27 vps sm-mta[28178]: r6NNcp6u021157: to=<user@email.co.uk>, ctladdr=<www-data@sergeserver> (33/33), delay=3+15:47:36, xdelay=00:02:06, mailer=esmtp, pri=47557620, relay=email.co.uk. [62.116.143.15], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with email.co.uk.
```

And a few of these:

```
Jul 27 17:40:01 vps sm-msp-queue[28198]: My unqualified host name (sergeserver) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jul 27 17:41:01 vps sm-msp-queue[28198]: unable to qualify my own domain name (sergeserver) -- using short name
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I don't have any code on me but the same issue is experienced with a number of wordpress plugins that utilize the `mail()` function. For the sake of this question you can assume a `mail()` script [in the simplest form](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3345) produces the problem

Comment: It's actually not an assumption. The most basic of `mail()` scripts does produce this problem, as I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

well you can try increasing those variables, i don't know the actual default value, usually around 30 or 60 seconds.

```
client_header_timeout N;
client_body_timeout N;
send_timeout N;
fastcgi_read_timeout N;
```

you can set them in the location that sends the email for example so you don't set this as a default value for all locations.
Of course you should replace N with a time period, like `30s` for 30 seconds or `2m` for 2 minutes.

Comment: surely it shouldn't take more than 30 seconds to send a text-only email